# Problems after adding Control dynamically on Panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, panel

I have added an View List onto a Panel like this:

```
panelComponent.Controls.Add(viewListComponent);
```

Everything works just fine. Mouse events are handled, repainting works. But one problem: I can't move it around dynamically. If I change the `control.Top` variable, it just sits there without moving.

It's like the control is glued to the top left corner. Resizing the right and bottom properties works just fine! I did it without dynamically adding and then no problem.

What could be causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't need to move controls at runtime. The framework provides a variety of mechanisms for layout management such as anchors, docking, and specialized layout containers. Here's a good read on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951306.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Two possible explanations.  First is the Dock property, docking it to the top keeps the control at the top of the container, no matter what you assign to the Top or Location properties.

The other one is value types, the Location property is Point, a struct.  This code will not move the control:

```
        var lbl = new Label();
        panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        var pos = lbl.Location;
        pos.Y = 42;  // No effect
```

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of `Dock` while writing about `Anchor`. Anyway, the described problem seems even more implausible now.

Comment: ok, i in the option panel is no docking. Locked False, Anchor is Top Left. Could that be the problem? Strange, i thought i did something wrong. like begin at the start. So i added randomly some controls. They all jump to the top of the panel. I cant move them around, even in the gui desinger!

Comment: On my Gui i have a Split Container. If i add the Control to its Panels direkt - horay i can move them. But if i add an Panel ON the Split Container (to have an LayoutManager) nothing. No move what so evar!

Comment: Erm, what's a LayoutManager?  It certainly *does* sound that layout is getting managed...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Location` property:

```
viewListComponent.Location = new Point(42, 42);
```